# Schengen visa for UK citizen?

Tags: visas, europe, schengen, eu, uk-citizens

Since I am a UK citizen I require a Schengen VISA to pass through Europe when I go travelling this year.

However where do I get one, I have checked the EU Parliament site and cannot find anything about it.

Where is the official place to get one? I see there are sites online that do the application for you for $30 however they seem a bit risky.

How long does the Schengen last for?

How much does it cost?

Do I need to reapply for it after entering a new EU country?

One site says you get it from the country you will be spending the most time in (which for me will be France), is this true?

**Sources**

- http://www.visaguru.co.uk/schengen-visas.html
- http://www.schengenvisa.cc/
- http://www.theschengenoffice.com/explained/schengen_visa.html

Comment: um, if you're a UK citizen, you really DON'T need a Schengen...

Comment: the documentation isnt clear though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since you are a citizen of the European Union you do not need a visa to travel to any other EU country. UK is not part of the Schengen Area, so you only need a passport (or national identity card) to cross the border and that's it.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_in_the_European_Union#Visa_requirements_for_the_Schengen_Area.2C_Bulgaria.2C_Cyprus_and_Romania):

*Individuals from the following countries can enter the Schengen Area, Bulgaria,[3] Cyprus,[4] and Romania[5] without a visa:
As of right, using a passport or national identity card*

*- **Citizens of European Union member states** and their special territories*

Comment: Not only do you not need a visa, you can and should use the EU/EEA queues (where available) at the border.

Answer (score 12):

I assure you, as a UK Citizen you're a member of the EU, and can travel anywhere in that area without restriction.  Travelling to France is Easy - you can fly, train, or take the ferry, and as long as you have your passport with you, or national ID card, you'll be absolutely fine.

Schengen is for people from other countries who may need a vetting process before coming into the EU - see Indian passports, or South African, but certainly not UK or any other member of the EU.

Answer (score 9):

If you hold a UK passport, then you hold a EU passport. You can legally live, work, travel and holiday in any other EU country for as long as you like, without requiring a visa.

The UK (along with Ireland and some others) are not in Schengen (some countries are in Schengen but not the EU (like Norway)). Schengen is only to make things much easier at borders. If you are in the Schengen area you don't need a passport to go from one schengen country to another. Makes it much easier if you, say, France, and lots of people are going from one country to the other.

You don't need a visa to go around the EU. You just need your passport.

Answer (score 1):

As other's have stated, being a citizen of the UK you do not need to apply for a schengen visa. UK is part of the EU therefore you can travel as much as you would like to throughout the Schengen Area.

However if you were only a resident of the UK w/o full citizenship, you would only be able to stay the maximum of 90 days in a 180 day period (the days are accumulative & can be non-consecutive).

check out our site for detailed information regarding the schengen visa.

[Schengen Visa HQ | Schengen Via Application: Do You Need One?](http://www.schengenvisahq.com/2012/05/26/schengen-visa-application-do-you-need-one/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said: if you're not an EU citizen you need to get a visa from the embassy of any Schengen signatory nation, probably your first port of entry, which should be good for all of them.

Comment: NOT the port of entry; rather, the country in which you are going to spend the most time.

Comment: This really depends on your personal situation. Some times there might not be an embassy available of the country you spent most of your time. In that case you need to go to the embassy of port of entry. The best way is to just call some of the available embassies. Once you have schengen visa it doesn't really matter which country issued

Comment: This is really not correct. There are plenty of countries which get visa-free entry to the Schengen zone for basic tourism or business trips (USA, Australia, Canada, etc...)

Comment: @andra: If your main destination country (D) has no embassy in the country from which you are applying (A), it is not true that you can choose any other Schengen country.  Rather, A will have identified another EU country (R) to serve as its representative in A, you will be required to apply at R's consulate.  For example, Portugal has no embassy in Bosnia and Herzegovina, so Schengen visa applicants in that country are required to submit their applications to the embassy of Slovenia.  See http://www.secomunidades.pt/vistos/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=188&Itemid=152